# openssl ca vs openssl x509 (the openssl ca command doesn't register the same on certificate?)

Tags: ssl, openssl

what is the difference between `openssl ca` and `openssl x509` commands? I'm using it to create and sign my root-ca, intermed-ca and clients certificates, but the `openssl ca` command does not register the cellphone and emailAddress on the certificates while `openssl x509` does.

**openssl x509:**

```
openssl x509 -req \
-in client.req.pem \
-out client.cert.pem -signkey client.privkey.pem \
-CA ca.cert.pem -CAkey ca.key.pem -CAcreateserial -days 365
```

**openssl ca:**

```
openssl ca \
-in client.req.pem \
-out client.cert.pem \
-extensions client_ext \
-startdate `date +%y%m%d000000Z -u -d -2day` \
-enddate `date +%y%m%d000000Z -u -d +1years+1day`
```

**My ca.cnf**

```
CA_HOME                 = .
RANDFILE                = $ENV::CA_HOME/private/.rnd
#oid_section             = new_oids

# XMPP address Support
#[ new_oids ]
#xmppAddr          = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.8.5
#dnsSRV            = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.8.7

# Default Certification Authority
[ ca ]
default_ca              = intermed_ca

# Intermediate Certification Authority
[ intermed_ca ]
dir                     = $ENV::CA_HOME
certs                   = $dir/certs
serial                  = $dir/intermed-ca.serial
database                = $dir/intermed-ca.index
new_certs_dir           = $dir/newcerts
certificate             = $dir/intermed-ca.cert.pem
private_key             = $dir/private/intermed-ca.key.pem
default_days            = 730 # Two years
crl                     = $dir/crl/intermed-ca.crl
crl_dir                 = $dir/crl
crlnumber               = $dir/intermed-ca.crlnum
name_opt                = multiline, align
cert_opt                = no_pubkey
copy_extensions         = copy
crl_extensions          = crl_ext
default_crl_days        = 30
default_md              = sha256
preserve                = no
email_in_dn             = no
policy                  = policy
unique_subject          = no

#
# Distinguished Name Policy
[ policy ]
countryName             = optional
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = optional
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied

#
# Distinguished Name Policy for Personal Certificates
[ user_policy ]
countryName             = supplied
stateOrProvinceName     = optional
localityName            = supplied
organizationName        = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = supplied
#xmppAddr               = optional # Added to SubjAltName by req

#
# Intermediate CA request options
[ req ]
default_bits            = 3072
default_keyfile         = private/intermed-ca.key.pem
encrypt_key             = yes
default_md              = sha256
string_mask             = utf8only
utf8                    = yes
prompt                  = no
req_extensions          = req_ext
distinguished_name      = distinguished_name
subjectAltName          = subject_alt_name

#
# Intermediate CA Request Extensions
[ req_ext ]
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
subjectAltName          = @subject_alt_name

#
# Distinguished Name (DN)
[ distinguished_name ]
countryName             = BR
stateOrProvinceName     = mystate
localityName            = mycity
organizationName        = domain.com
organizationalUnitName  = P&D
commonName              = domain.com.br Intermediate Certification Authority
emailAddress            = my.email@domain.com

#
# Server Certificate Extensions
[ server_ext ]
basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage                = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage        = critical, serverAuth, clientAuth
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always
issuerAltName           = issuer:copy
authorityInfoAccess     = @auth_info_access
crlDistributionPoints   = crl_dist

#
# Client Certificate Extensions
[ client_ext ]
basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage                = critical, digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage        = critical, clientAuth
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always
issuerAltName           = issuer:copy
authorityInfoAccess     = @auth_info_access
crlDistributionPoints   = crl_dist

#
# User Certificate Extensions
[ user_ext ]
basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage                = critical, digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage        = critical, clientAuth, emailProtection
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always
issuerAltName           = issuer:copy
authorityInfoAccess     = @auth_info_access
crlDistributionPoints   = crl_dist

#
# CRL Certificate Extensions
[ crl_ext ]
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always
issuerAltName           = issuer:copy

#
# Certificate Authorities Alternative Names
[ subject_alt_name ]
URI                     = http://ca.domain.com/
email                   = contato@domain.com

#
# Certificate download addresses for the intermediate CA
[ auth_info_access ]
caIssuers;URI           = http://ca.domain.com/certs/domain.com_Intermediate_Certification_Authority.cert.pem

#
# CRL Download address for the intermediate CA
[ crl_dist ]
fullname                = URI:http://ca.domain.com/crl/domain.com_Intermediate_Certification_Authority.crl
```

**Reference**

https://roll.urown.net/ca/ca_root_setup.html

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The most notable difference is that you can only generate CRLs using the "ca" utility. It's because it that I'm using `ca`

Answer (score 6):

From the man page for ca(1) (ca(1ssl) or similar on some systems), emphasis added:

> POLICY FORMAT
>
> The policy section consists of a set of variables corresponding to certificate DN fields. If the value is "match" then the field value must match the same field in the CA certificate. If the value is "supplied" then it must be present. If the value is "optional" then it may be present. **Any [DN] fields not mentioned in the policy section are silently deleted, unless the -preserveDN option is set[,] but this can be regarded more of a quirk than intended behaviour.**

And later:

> BUGS
> ...
> **Any [DN] fields in a request that are not present in a policy are silently deleted. This does not happen if the -preserveDN option is used.** To enforce the absence of the EMAIL field within the DN, as suggested by RFCs, regardless [of] the contents of the request'[s] subject[,] the -noemailDN option can be used. The behaviour should be more friendly and configurable.

And although these only mention the commandline option `-preserveDN`, elsewhere it (incompletely) describes this related configuration item:

> preserve
> the same as -preserveDN

To be exact, if `preserve` **is `yes`** it overrides the policy and retains all DN fields (in order), as (correctly) documented for `-preserveDN`, but your posted file has `preserve = no`.

---

I also notice you specified `-extensions` in your `ca` but not in your `x509`. `ca` can put extensions in the cert from the config file if you specify commandline option `-extensions` OR config item `x509_extensions` (which your posted file doesn't) AND ALSO can copy extensions from the CSR (if any, which you don't indicate) if you specify config item `copy_extensions` (which you do). `x509` can put extensions only from a config file (never the CSR) and only if you specify on commandline `-extfile file` and optionally `-extensions section`. This will produce a very important difference in your certs, likely more important than email and phone# in subject, and is already covered by other Qs like https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150078/missing-x509-extensions-with-an-openssl-generated-certificate and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371997/creating-a-local-ssl-certificate

Comment: Very informative thanks to those links provided at the bottom of the Answer, in fact I could read all of them and have a much bigger understanding of all these configuration file options.